# How to divide gridview in sections in android?

Tags: android, gridview, adapter

My question is basic but I couldn't find any answer for my question. I have a layout which contains 2 *textviews* and a *gridview*. I added this layout into a *listview*.I want to generate multiple layouts. For example;

```
ListView------------------1stElement
----------textview1-----------------
----------gridview1-----------------
----------textview1-----------------
ListView------------------2ndElement
----------textview2-----------------
----------gridview2-----------------
----------textview2-----------------
ListView------------------3rdElement
----------textview3-----------------
----------gridview3-----------------
----------textview3-----------------
```

I tried it like that;

```
for(int i = 0; i<category.getChildren().size(); i++){

    listView.setAdapter(new CategoryListAdapter(this, category.getChildren().get(i)));
 }
```

But of course, it showed my last view only. **setAdapter()** doesn't suit to my code. I need something like adding views over and over.

Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do this in for loop, Adapter Takes whole list Once Only, If u do it in a loop it will set the last list  visible, So make list in For loop first and then add i to adapter only once.

```
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
   ArrayList<Object> myChldrenList  = new ArrayList<Object>();
   Object mychild = mycategory.getChildren().get(i)
   myChildrenList.add(myChild);
}

 listView.setAdapter(new CategoryListAdapter(this, myChildrenList));
```

u can use Ur Class type Instead of object class or simply Type Cast Object Class.